# How to split path with slashes?

Tags: python

I have a requirement for adding and splitting path in my app.I want to work with this app on windows and linux.Here is my code to add paths

```
 path = os.path.join(dir0,dir1,dir2,fn)
```

But when i am splitting with slashes i am facing problems .Because

the path in windows like:

```
dir0\dir1\dir2\fn
```

the path in linux like

```
dir0/dir1/dir2/fn
```

Now how can i split the path with single code(with out changing the code while using other platform/platform independent)

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem?

Comment: why do you need to splash as long as you have dir0, dir1, dir2, fn? aren't these the elements of the splashed path?

Comment: @msvalkon,Yes those are the part of path of my file,So i need to save my path in database,And later i want to split that path form static onwards for displaying that image in webpage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split). It is a system independent way to split paths. Note that this only splits into `(head, tail)`. To get all the individual parts, you need to recursively split `head` or use `str.split` using `os.path.sep` as the separator.

Comment: ,Thank you.Then how to take the tail part into a variable

Comment: head, tail = os.path.split(path)

Comment: Thank you brother,its working.I think you are from India. Thank you again

Answer (score 15):

You can use `os.sep`

just

```
import os
path_string.split(os.sep)
```

For more info, look the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

> os.path.join(path1[, path2[, ...]])
>   Join one or more path components intelligently. If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues. The return value is the concatenation of path1, and optionally path2, etc., with exactly one directory separator (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the last. (This means that an empty last part will result in a path that ends with a separator.) Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.